# Perform multiple ASP.NET Core Identity UserManager calls atomically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

In my system, username and email are the same. I want to make multiple `UserManager` calls atomically, e.g.

```cs
userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(...);
userManager.SetUserNameAsync(...);
```

On [the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10260) it was explained that this cannot be done with `UserManager`, as it doesn't directly support transactions.

However `UserManager` relies on a `DbContext`. Is there a way to use a context transaction to perform an atomic operation as above?

Comment: Looks like this is [not possible](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19165#issuecomment-600813339), because every `UserManager` method is committed individually. However that comment was from **two years ago** - maybe there is a way today?